# Android - Java - MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE

Tags: java, android, cordova, native

I am working with Phonegap / Cordova 3.3 in Android and am trying to create a native plugin using Java. The function I am trying to call is the MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE. Here is my code.

```
...

File file = new File(filePath);

Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE");
mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);

this.cordova.getActivity().sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);

...
```

The code seems to execute fine. However, the file does not get added to the media library. I am passing the full path name to the function.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you hardcode the filePath?
Take a look at this post http://androidyue.github.io/blog/2014/01/19/scan-media-files-in-android/  It's expressed in detail. 
I hope this could help you.

Comment: Thanks! I have spent a lot of time on this problem.